# Proper Firebase Firestore 'Like' Database Structure in Swift

Tags: database, firebase, data-structures, google-cloud-firestore

So I've searched quite a bit on implementing this and can't seem to find a best practice for how to structure my database.

I'm creating an iOS app using Firebase's new database Firestore.

Essentially I have two main 'collections'.

'users'
'locations'

There are 100 locations.
Users are infinite.
Users can 'like' locations.
Users can 'follow' other users.

Where I'm running into an issue is querying for the currentUsers 'liked' locations and 'followed' users.

Should these be objects within the user? for example...

```
/users
    /userId
         name:"Phil"
         likedLocations
             location1:true
             location5:true
         followedUsers
             userId3:true
             userId6:true
```

Or should these be in the 'locations' collection...

```
/locations
    /locationId
         name:"New York"
         userLiked
             "userId":true
```

For ease of editing I may go in manually to the database and edit a Location.  With Option A - that's no issue.  Users have a possibility of having 100 items in their 'likedLocations'.  With Option B - a location could have infinite (as many users as in the app) key value pairs.

Comment: TLDR - what is the most easily queried and cost effective way to set up a user following/liking type database.

Comment: go with the first. you can only have 20000 users for New York in the second example. While, it would be unlikely that Phil will have liked 20000 places.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use these two root collections?

```
/likedPlaces
   /userId
      name: "Phil"
      location: locationId

/followers (or followed. Based on your query needs)
   /userId
      name: otherUserId
```

This way a certain user can query :

- all his liked places
- filter for some of them
- all his followers by their id
- check if a user is his follower.

Does it make sense? Hope it helps.
Alessandro